# No random access method for Java Set

Tags: java, collections, set

I wonder why there is no random access method `get(Object)` like `Map` in Java `Set`. In current implementation iterating the whole collection seems as unnecessary overhead.

Comment: That's how a set/bag works by design.

Comment: @duffymo, I don't think so. There's nothing preventing a direct membership test of whether an element is in a Set. Nothing in the design forces iteration

Comment: What key do you plan to use to access the element?  I think the behavior is more like a bag: reach in and grab an arbitrary one.  I'd cite the lack in the API as proof of my statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
> boolean   contains(Object o)
Returns true if this set contains the specified element.
```

(from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: But the time complexity is O(n), which is not effecient compared to `get()` random access method.

Comment: Where does it say the complexity is O(n)? It depends on what's actually implementing the interface. A HashSet would be O(1)

Comment: Java (6) source http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/HashSet.java shows it just calls `containsKey` on the HashMap. No iteration over the set involved

Answer (score 4):

A `Set` is not *about* random element retrieval—it is about testing for the existence of elements in it. If your application calls for retrieval, then what it actually needs is an identity mapping (a map where you `put(key, key)`). Then you will be able to `get` the object just as you want. Also note that you won't be incurring any overheads by doing so because a `HashSet` is implemented in terms of a `HashMap` in almost exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out a `Set` is modeled more or less after a mathematical set and does not concern itself with random access. However, if you absolutely have to access one element you can do something like this:

```
Set<Object> mySet = new HashSet<Object>();
mySet.add("one");
Object access = mySet.toArray()[0];
```